# How can I implement fingerprint scanner with MERN stack app?

Tags: mern, fingerprint

I want to build a mearn stack web application where I need to read data from an external fingerprint device and store the data into the MongoDB database for future operations.
It might be compared with the attendance system. Is there any NPM package to read the data from the fingerprint device?
Thanking you..